# How to get array containing n elements with equal step between them using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given `[a, b]` and `n`. My goal is to get array `[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]` which contains `n` elements with equal step between them. How can I do it using `numpy`?

Comment: `numpy.linspace` suits the use case better. Do you have reasons to specifically use `numpy.arange`?

Comment: No I don't. Your solution suits perfectly, thanks!

Comment: `np.r_[a,b,n]` is also an option

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [np.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

```
np.linspace(a,b,n)
```